How to sign in to Google account without typing username or password?
I added a passkey to my Google account. When I log in, after typing my username, there's an option to use a passkey instead of typing my password.
Is it possible to login without typing my username at all? This would be great.

Questions about computers, web browsers and browser profiles are normally on-topic on [su]. Helpful Q & A though

According to How do I sign in with a passkey instead of a password?:

When you tap on the username field, you may see a list of passkeys. If so, tap the passkey you’d like to use.

Chrome
In Google Chrome (Windows) look for "Use a passkey"

Safari
In iOS Safari ignore the big blue button, look for the small key button, then select a passkey:

